# Have page render, then execute method, and then redirect to page provided by method

Tags: visualforce

I have a multi-step object load process that uses web callouts to populate detail records for a newly created master object.

I've been able to create a Visualforce page and a controller extension to handle the loading, by making one callout, encoding the result (X records loaded) in a query string parameter, and then having the page reload (to trigger the next step).

I use the `action` attribute of the `apex:page` tag to kick off the load process.  Unfortunately, that means the page doesn't render during the callout which can take a few seconds.

I'm looking for a way I can do the following:

1) Display the rendered page (so I can have a message, "Loading FooBars...").

2) Have a method called automatically (I've considered using JavaScript to call the method, possibly via an `onload` callback).

3) Possibly redirect to the same page, with a different query string.

On item #3, I could probably get away with just updating part of the screen (maybe in an `apex:actionStatus`) and then triggering the next method via JavaScript, but I'll eventually want to redirect to the standard Detail view for the master object after all steps complete.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can have your onload JS function in which you can show your loading image etc.
Then call apex:actionfunction that will call the webservice in the backend. Also this will have rerender attribute populated to re-render the page.
And finally in the apexfunction you will have oncomplete attribute (another JS function) that will hide the loading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I've been able to work out so far.  On my VisualForce page, I have a bunch of `apex:actionFunction` entries for each step of the process:

```
  <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="step1" status="step1_status" rerender="step1_status"
      action="{!step1Method}" oncomplete="step2();"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="step2" status="step2_status" rerender="step2_status"
      action="{!step2Method}" oncomplete="step3();"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="step3" status="step3_status" rerender="step3_status"
      action="{!step3Method}" oncomplete="finalRedirect();"/>
  </apex:form>
```

Then I include multiple `apex:actionStatus` elements on the page:

```
  <apex:actionStatus id="stepX_status" startText="loading..." stopText="{!stepX_status}"/>
```

And end the page with JavaScript:

```
  <script>
    step1();
    function finalRedirect()
    {
        window.location = "{!URLFOR($Action.SomeObject__c.View, SomeObject__c.Id)}";
    }
  </script>
```

In my controller extension:

```
public String step1_status { get; private set; }
public String step2_status { get; private set; }
public String step3_status { get; private set; }

public SomeObjectExtension( ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
    step1_status = '';
    step2_status = '';
    step3_status = '';
}

// each step has its own method
public void stepXMethod()
{
    // do stuff that might take a few seconds

    // update stopText of actionStatus on web page
    stepX_status = 'Status to display on web page';
}
```

And it's working smoothly now.  The `<script>` at the end of the page kicks off the process.  Each `actionFunction` is asynchronous, but upon completion of one step, it automatically starts the next step with the `oncomplete` property.  When the last step completes, it sets `window.location` to redirect the browser to the detail page for the object.